# How to defining a bean in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am facing an issue with my Spring Boot application. When trying to run the application, I am getting the error message "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.task_manager.backend.appController required a bean of type 'com.task_manager.backend.TaskRepository' that could not be found." Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Error message:
`Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.task_manager.backend.appController required a bean of type 'com.task_manager.backend.TaskRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.task_manager.backend.TaskRepository' in your configuration.
`

I have already checked my code and made sure that the TaskRepository interface is defined and imported correctly. I have also checked the application properties file and made sure that the database connection details are correct.

Controller.java

```
package com.task_manager.backend;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@Data
public class appController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("Users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("addUser")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return  userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.task_manager.backend;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;




}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.task_manager.backend;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

note  : all files in the same package

Comment: Where is the relation to `TaskRepository` in your code? I don't see any `TaskRepository` in `appController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all- It is recommended to place the Main Application class in the root package with annotations like `@SpringBootApplication`(combination of `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@Configuration`). It allows the Spring to scan all classes in the root package and sub-packages. Reference to read about this- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html
According to this, move your main class to root package `com.task_manager` and controller class inside the `com.task_manager.backend`

Now try this

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class appController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("Users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("addUser")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return  userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

```
For lombok, Make sure you have enabled annotation processor in your IDE.
```

When using a constructor to set injected properties, you do not have to provide the `@Autowired` annotation. Annotation of constructors for dependency injection has been optional since Spring Framework version 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Move your main class BackendApplication  from

```
package com.task_manager.backend
```

to

```
package com.task_manager
```

And make sure your controller has this code

```
 @RestController
 public class appController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRestController(UserRepository theUserRepository ) {
        userRepository = theUserRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return  userRepository.save(user);
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Constructor method in appController like this:

```
public appController(UserRepository userRepository){
    this.userRepository= userRepository;
}
```

Or adding an annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` above the class of `appController`

Answer (score 1):

Add @Autowired in private final UserRepository userRepository;

```
package com.task_manager.backend;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@Data
public class appController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("Users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("addUser")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return  userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```